# How to pass environment variables to Tox before installing deps?

Tags: python, pycurl, tox

I need 3 env variables in order to install pycurl.
When i use Tox, i can't pass my env variables to the Tox environment before it runs the deps installation command.

I already tried using `setenv` and `passenv`, but both passes the env variables to the environment after the installation ends.
I also can't set the env variables through commands because it says that `export` command is not found.

This is my tox.ini:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27
skipsdist = True

[testenv:py27]
deps = -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
       -r{toxinidir}/requirements_test.txt

[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
    PYTHONHASHSEED = 0
commands = pytest {toxinidir}/tests
```

My env variables are:

```
PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can override [`install_command`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command) with a command or even a script that sets your env variables.

Comment: I already tried it, it does not work

Comment: Can you show what you did and how it doesn't work? I'd like to try your code myself.